# Strip null union from interface / type property

Tags: typescript

I am looking for a way to strip the null union type from a specific property of a object type / interface.

```
type User = {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string | null;
};


type g = NonNullableProp<User, 'lastName'>
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this does the trick

```
type User = {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string | null;
};

export type NonNullableProp<T, K> = { [P in keyof T]: P extends K ? NonNullable<T[P]> : T[P]}
type g = NonNullableProp<User, 'lastName'>
```